# Using Connection Names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there anyway to use the Connection Names rather than the connection link in the Excel formulas?

Example:

Connection Name - Test1

Connection Link - www.www.www.com

Current Equation - `=IF('www.www.www.com[test1.xlsm]Sheet1!'K1=0, "--", 'www.www.www.com[test1.xlsm]Sheet1!'K1)`

Desired Equation - `=IF('Test1'Sheet1!K1=0, "--", 'Test1'Sheet1!K1)`

Does anyone know if its possible?  My addresses are really long and would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Indirect - which uses the content of a cell in a formula - rather than its address.

As such, for your example - you could have the string `'www.www.www.com[test1.xlsm]Sheet1!'K1` in a cell - such as A1 then in your formula you could refer to it as `=IF(INDIRECT(A1)>0,"--",INDIRECT(A1))`

Other than that, you'd probably have to look at a custom vba function. (I'll not go into that with the lack of tag)